# React-Redux: Get method when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a list, in which every element has an id. When I click in a button linked to this id, I would redirect in a page in which I do a get using this id.

So when I click on the button I'm redirect to another page, with the id in the props.

Information.js

```
    class Information extends Component {


    render()
    let idmeeting = this.props.location.state
    console.log(idmeeting);
    console.log(this.props.meetingDetail)

    // I have tried something like this but it doesn't work (maybe I don't have wrote in the right way
    function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return { 
    idmeeting: ownProps.location.state,
    meetingDetail: state,
  };
}


    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        meetingInformation: (idmeeting) => dispatch(meetingInformation(idmeeting)),
      };
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Information);
```

And at the end this is the action:

```
export const Information = (idmeeting) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(
      api.meeting + '/' + idmeeting,
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
    )
    .then(
      (response) => response.json(),
      (error) => console.log("An error occurred.", error)
    )
    .then((meetingDetail) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "INFORMATION",
        meetingDetail: meetingDetail
      });
    });
  }
}
```

How Can I do to make the get call when the button (on List.js) is clicked to display in Information.js??

Thank you.

EDIT:

Information.js

```
    class Information extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
    this.props.meetingInformation(this.props.location.state)
    //I console log the fetch and it receives the id
    }

    render()
    console.log(this.props.meetingDetail)
    //this one prints the previous list of meetings plus one undefined

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { 
    meetingDetail: state,
  };
}


    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        meetingInformation: (meetingDetail) => dispatch(meetingInformation(meetingDetail)),
      };
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Information);
```

`this.props.meetingDetail` before the api call:

> `(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

`this.props.meetingDetail` after the api call:

> `((10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, Array(1)]`

Reducers.js

```
export const reducer = (state = [] , action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INFORMATION':
            return [...state, action.meetingDetail]
        default: 
            return state;
    }

}

export default reducer;
```

Comment: can you add the output of console.log(this.props.meetingDetail). Since, you are assigning the whole redux state to this.props.meetingDetail, its hard to tell without the actual output.

Comment: I have edit the question

Comment: In your action make sure the `meetingDetail` in the second `then` block isn't undefined. As per your redux state you are passing an `undefined` value to your reducer.

Comment: meetingDetail is the same of the `this.props.meetings` In the List.js

Comment: Ok in the second .then I have insert a console.log(meetingDetail) and it prints only information about the meeting so it works and  So it isn't undefined. I have resolve the problem about undefined, the only problem is that it is joined to the previous list( I have edited the question one more time with the new console.log)

Comment: That reduces the problem to the `reducer`. Since, the state is updating at the reducer and the value you passed in the action `INFORMATION` is valid, you need to make sure that you are updating the store correctly.

Comment: I think so, I have add also the code of reducers. I don't understand because it should take a new state every time, not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211797/discussion-between-slumbergeist-and-jack23).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your code is here:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return { 
    idmeeting: ownProps.this.props.location.state,
    meeting: state,
  };
}
```

ownProps contains props of component and you don't need **this.props** on it anymore.
so please try this instead:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return { 
    idmeeting: ownProps.location.state,
    meeting: state,
  };
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code, insert some console log and what you said. 
`console.log(idmeeting);` prints the right idmeeting
 `console.log(this.props.meetingDetail)` prints the all list of meetings that coming from the list

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lifecycle methods such as componentDidMount to trigger the information action which contains the get request

Comment: Mmh what I should insert in the componentDidMount() ?

Comment: Ok i Have add the this component to do the get but now I receive a 500 error because I don't pass the idmeeting to the api

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to make a request when the `Information` page mounts, just use `componentDidMount` to dispatch your action.

```
class Information extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.meetingInformation(this.props.location.state);
  }
  render()
  //....



}
```

If you are not able to access the prop passed to your route or `this.props.location.state` is undefined, this is most probably due to how you have defined your route via. React-router. In any case you can merge the route `props` directly to the components `props` using the `withRouter` HOC. You would have to import the said HOC

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
```

then update your component export to

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(Information));
```

Comment: Ok In this way I pass the meeting id to the GET method, but  my `console.log(this.props.meetingDetail)` in the render  prints the previous meetings plus a new one that is undefined

Comment: I have edit my code using some information that you give